# How to add a navigation controller to a view-based application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

Is it possible to add a `UINavigationController` to a view application that inherits from `UIViewController` and not `UITableViewController`? How is it done?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you can have Navigation controllers in any view based application, whether at the Root level (like when you create the Navigation-based template in Xcode) or with a TabBar root, or with any Root.

One example, presenting a modal view including navigation (used in my app to display a series of forms):

```
    UIViewController *control = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MyViewController" bundle: nil];
    UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: control];
    [self presentModalViewController: navControl animated: YES];
    [control release];
```

In another example, if you want to have it at the root level, but didn't create the application with the Navigation template, in the AppDelegate's didFinishLaunching(...):

```
    UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: control];
    [window setRootViewController: navControl];
    [navControl release];
```

You can also set it in Interface Builder, by setting up the class of the View controller you use (UIViewController replaced by UINavigationController).

I hope this answers your question (sorry about the previous discussion).

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample code to understand how to build a UITabBarController which is create with Container of viewcontroller including several navigationcontroller https://github.com/damienromito/CustomTabBarController